# How can i detect the remove of a specific package in android?

Tags: android, package

Is it possible to detect the remove of a specific application in android? If yes how ? this my code that detect the remove of any package, how can i change it to detect the desired application ?

```
import android.content.*;
import android.util.Log;

public class PackageChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"))   {Log.i("action","the package is removed");}
}
}
```

and this is the manifest

```
<receiver android:name="PackageChangeReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
<data android:scheme="package"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can filter the broadcasts for a specific package name. However, you can retrieve (and then test) the package name easily enough when you receive the broadcast:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String pkg = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
```

(There's a nice sample class, [PackageMonitor](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/content/PackageMonitor.java.shtml), at [DevDaily.com](http://devdaily.com/) that was my source for the above code fragment.)

Comment: But please don't do this unless you really, really need to.  There are very few reasons to actually need to do this.  It would be really nice if you could post what you are trying to accomplish with this, so the underlying need can be addressed.  It is obnoxious of apps to do this for no good reason, because it means every time the user installs or updates an app you get launched.  Now if 10 of the apps the user has on their devices does this, they are causing a crappy experience.  Don't be one of those apps.

Comment: @emna - I second hackbod's comment. What are you trying to accomplish that leads to doing this?

Comment: I'm developping an application of tracking mobile that helps people to retreive there mobiles in case of theft. So in case of uninstall of the app, at least the user can delete his data

Comment: @emna - If your app uses [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) or [`getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) to store files, then all app data (including preferences and data bases) will be automatically deleted when the app is uninstalled. There's no need to monitor the package itself.

Comment: No i will developp 2 application one that track the mobile and the other delete data

Comment: @emna - Well, that's your business, but I'll make one last stab: I don't see any reason for this. As hackbod points out, your app to delete data will be fired up for every package change on your device. As long as you use application-private areas to store your data, the data will be automatically deleted by the system. Registering a broadcast listener will just degrade the user experience.